# Error when using CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am trying to use the [CarrierWaveDirect](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct) gem in conjunction with the [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) gem, but I am getting an error when rendering the direct upload form. This is in development, haven't tried in production yet. Here is the form:

**/app/views/users/registrations/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

The error is on the `<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>` line, and is

```
ArgumentError in Users/registrations#edit
 is not a recognized storage provider
```

**UPDATE:**

I've worked out that making any change to the controller code, after the development server has been started, makes it work. For example, if I add a simple `p "test"` line anywhere in the controller, it works. If I then stop the development server and restart it, the error will occur again, but if I take out the `p "test"` line, it will work. *So I'm guessing that for some reason, a configuration setting is not being set correctly when the server is started, and making a change to the controller's code causes something to be reloaded, which sets it correctly?*

**/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
  def edit
    @uploader = User.new.image
    @uploader.success_action_redirect = process_user_avatar_url
    super
  end
```

**/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

**/app/models/user.rb**

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

**/config/initializers/s3.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => KEY,
    :aws_secret_access_key  => SECRET,
  }
  if Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_directory  = PRODUCTION_BUCKET
  else
    config.fog_directory  = DEVELOPMENT_BUCKET
  end
  config.fog_public     = false
end
```

**Versions**

```
Rails 3.2.0
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
carrierwave (0.6.2)
carrierwave_direct (0.0.6)
fog (1.5.0)
```

**development.rb**

```
Appname::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
  config.whiny_nils = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
  config.assets.compress = false
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.log_level = :warn
end
```

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. What did I do wrong?

Comment: are you only using direct_upload_form_for in your registrations "edit"? or is it also in "new"?

Comment: @KyleC Only using it in "edit"

Comment: In your development.rb envirnonment, do you have config.cache_classes = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

Comment: @KyleC Yep. Added development.rb to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the following at the top of your model and controller:

```
require_dependency File.expand_path('../../uploaders/image_uploader', __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a really weird bug. I remember a while back when I built a rails application for a tutorial that my controller's were locking in and even if I deleted the action it didn't pick up.

I have two ideas ideas that I would try looking at.

1. What happens when you delete the `edit` action. Does the application break? If not, then you have a different problem.
2. When I created a test application to try `CarrierWave_Direct` I got the same `ArgumentError` when my initializer file was invalid. Try putting everything in statically to see if it gets your information properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a fix or just a workaround, but you might try adding to your initializer:

```
config.storage = :fog
```

or

```
config.storage = :file
```

You could also use directly in your uploader:

```
storage :fog
```

or

```
storage :file
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you locate carrierWave configure file in initializers folder ?
I think config file doesn't read.